# java XML to string issue

Tags: java, xml, transformer-model

I tried to solve my xml issue but I am stuck... I am getting the xml as `System.Out` at console quite well. However when I tried to get it as a return string value, it gives me only half of the xml (the returned string does not contain error but it's broken xml). The code is below. (ide: androidstudio, tried jdk 1.7/1.8 same result)

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
//initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);

// Output to console for testing
StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, consoleResult); // this give all data to as System.Out as correct every line

xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
Log.v("XML OUTPUT  xmlString", xmlString.toString()); // but this gives only part of xml like broken from half part...
```

Update:
Solution, there is nothing wrong but Log.v cuts string... this means code is working. thanks for tip to @wero

Comment: Can you paste the result you get? Like a screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: because `Log.v` cuts off half of the string

Comment: @wero, thank you for tip, I have tried tooo much problem but I was not consider Log.v operations might do this to me... why it is cutting anyway.